# Datatable not updating based on filter when using module server in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I created a datatable and it was working fine when I used just the server function with App.R but when I moved to mod_dt.R so that I can modularize it and call again whenever I need to show other dataframe. Now the reactivity is somehow gone. Changing filter does not changes the display of the datatable. It seem to have filtered the data because when I click it nothing is click but the display does not change.

Here is mod_dt.R code

```
mod_dt_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    dataTableOutput(ns("dt"))
  )
}

mod_dt_Server <- function(id, dsin, RV) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns

      output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
        req(dsin)
        tmpdata = dsin
        
        for (i in 1:nrow(metadata)) {
          for (j in 1:length(names(tmpdata))) {
            if(metadata$variable[i] == names(tmpdata)[j]) {
              names(tmpdata)[j] = metadata$varlabel[i]
            }
          }
        }
        
        tmpdata 
      }, rownames = FALSE,
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                     searchHighlight = TRUE,
                     lengthMenu = c(10, 15, 25), 
                     pageLength = 6),
      selection = list(mode="single",target = 'cell'),
      extensions = list("ColReorder" = NULL,
                        "FixedColumns" = list(leftColumns=4))
      
      )
      session$allowReconnect(TRUE)
      
    }
  )
}
```

Here is how I call it in the server function in App.R

```
  mod_dt_Server(id="tbl1", dsin=RV$df, RV=RV)
```

In UI this is how I output

```
mod_dt_UI("tbl1")
```

RV$df is the dataset that is reactive and changes based on few filters I have created. I expected the display of the output to change when I filter dataset but the display does not change.

Any help on what I am missing here

Here is how the App.R looks like

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_dt_UI("tbl1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
observe({
    RV$df = df %>%
      filter(col1 %in% input$selectcol1) %>%  
      filter(col2 %in% input$selectcol2) %>%
      filter(col3 %in% input$selectcol3) %>%
      filter(col4 %in% input$selectcol4) %>%
      filter(AGE >= input$selectAGE[1] & AGE <= input$selectAGE[2])
})

mod_dt_Server(id="tbl1", dsin=RV$df, RV=RV)

}
```

Comment: Have you try init the reactive value by calling `RV <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)` in your app server function?

Also sinsce you passed `RV` into the module's server function, maybe you should use `RV$df` instead of `dsin` while calling `DT::renderDataTable()`

Comment: I tried passing RV$df instead of dsin but still having same issue. Main problem seems to be the datatable display is not updating because i have a code to print the clicked cells but when I click the cells after filtering (Remove all) I get NA in the Rstudio console but the UI for the datatable still shows the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle reactivity also inside module.

I suppose you have a more complete code where you define the inputs and the `metadata` object, so I'll skip to where I think your problem is.

You are creating a reactive value but not using it as reactive inside the module. Also ensure you are defining `df` as `reactiveVal`

```
server <- function...
    RV <- reactiveValues()
    RV$df <- reactiveVal()

    # I think is clearer to use reactiveVal as function call
    observe({ # Any reactivity wrapper would do, depending on needs
        RV$df(
            df %>%
                ...
        )
    })
    ...
    mod_dt_Server(id="tbl1", dsin=reactive(RV$df), metadata = metadata)
}
```

Then inside `mod_dt_Server`

```
    output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
        req(dsin())
        tmpdata = dsin()
    ...
```

This should re-render table when you filter it

Comment: I dont think the below part work because its a reactive value so need to be inside observe or reactive. Isnt it ?

RV$df(
        df %>%
            ...
    )

Comment: Thanks Amulya! I edited the response to specify the reactive environment